# How to emulate C++ `x=x&&f()` in bash

Tags: bash, short-circuiting

I'm writing this all over the place:

```
if (( $x == 0 )) ; then
    mycommand
    x=$?
fi
```

Is there a simpler/briefer way to do this with bash's short-circuiting `&&`?

EDIT:
I don't care about the value of `$x` other than it's zeroness i.e. success/failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, variable `x` is just the result of the previous command? If you mean that you have a continuous series of almost identical blocks like:

```
if (( $x == 0 )) ; then my_command_1; x=$?; fi
....
if (( $x == 0 )) ; then my_command_N; x=$?; fi
```

Then, just combine your commands this way

```
my_command_1 \
&& ... \
&& my_command_N
```

[update]

On the other hand, if the commands are scattered all over the script, I would do either:

```
x=true
$x && my_command_1 || x=false
...
$x && my_command_2 || x=false
```

Or, more discreet:

```
$do my_command_1 || do=:
...
$do my_command_2 || do=:
```

Or, more probably, through a function:

```
function check_and_do { [ -z "$failed" ] && "$@" || failed=ouch; }

check_and_do my_command_1
....
check_and_do my_command_2
```

Comment: The commands occur at many different places and scopes. Not in a continuous succession like that.

Comment: What's with `$do my_command || do=:`? How does `$do` decide whether `my_command` executes?

Comment: @Museful `do` is either undefined and `$do` evaluates to nothing => your command is run; OR `do` has been given the value `:` following an error, and `$do` evaluates to the null-command  `:` (its arguments, i.e. your command,  are ignored).

Comment: Would you mind removing the first half of this answer to make it more consistent with the question? I really like the second half.

Comment: @Museful I will shorten it a bit but it can't remove everything as it is relevant and might be useful for others

Answer (score 4):

```
(( x == 0 )) && { mycommand; x=$?; }
```

- Inside `(( ... ))` you generally don't need to prefix variables with `$`.
- `{ ... }` is a group command that allows you to execute multiple commands as a unit, in this case serving as the RHS to the `&&` operator.
  Note the need to terminate the last command inside `{ ... }` with `;` (in the single-line form).

---

Generally, **you can chain commands directly with `&&` (logical AND) and `||` (logical OR)**, but note that **these (short-circuiting) operators have *equal* precedence** (and are left-associative, as usual).

```
cmd1 && cmd2 && ... || cmdElse # first failing command triggers cmdElse
```

means that `cmd1` is executed unconditionally, and, if it succeeds (exit code `0`), all subsequent commands execute as long as they too succeed.
The *first* failing command (nonzero exit code), if any, triggers the `||` clause.

If, by contrast, you wanted to limit the `||` clause to a specific command, use a group command:

```
cmd1 && { cmd2 || cmd2Else; } # cmd2Else only executes if cmd2 gets to execute and fails
```

Now, `cmdElse` is only invoked if `cmd2` gets to execute at all and fails.

To illustrate the equal-precedence behavior:

```
cmd1 || cmd2 && cmd3 # conceptually: (cmd1 || cmd2) && cmd3
```

`cmd1` is executed unconditionally, and if it fails, `cmd2` is executed. If *either* succeeds, `cmd3` is executed.
If both fail, `cmd3` never gets to execute.